# Cancelling a \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote instance: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote

I am having a custom module that makes use of the \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote to retrieve the quote instance.
I am getting the quote details properly as expected.

Here I would like to cancel the quotes on clicking a Cancel Quote Button.

The cancel quote button is calling the controller for cancel.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo "Cancel Quote"; ?>" class="action-default scalable" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/cancel', ['quote_id' => $_quotes[0]['quote_id']]) ?>';">
```

Here I want to cancel my quotes in the controller function.

In order, we can cancel order using something like below,

```
/**
 * Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface orderManagement
 */
 $this->orderManagement->cancel($order->getEntityId());
```

Is there any way to achieve that with quotes?

I have already searched about it and gone through many links but they were not quite helpful in my case.

Please, can anyone help?